# Auto add dimension annotation to vector file

Tags: vector

Are there any software to auto add dimension annotation for vector file  ? 
for example 
[image]

Comment: There might be a plugin for Illustrator, but it is a normal feature in CAD programs. Take a look at LibreCAD for example. It's free and seems alright.

Comment: Your drawing is under constrained so a automatic dimensioning tool would make more dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Most mechanical CAD applications can do this. Inducing:

- Creo
- Solidworks
- NX
- Fusion 360
- [SolveSpace](http://solvespace.com/index.pl) (free)
- ...

However note the computer does not know which dimension scheme to use so you would still need to tweak the results in most cases. Anyway please note that not all cads work this way for example Catia V5 does not and same applies to FreeCAD which attempts to be everything that is bad about Catia.

Anyway cad applications are bidirectional. So if you change the value of a dimension then the drawing will change to match suit.

[image]

Image 1: CAD applications retain dimensions and react to dimension changes

Comment: Corel Draw also has an auto dimension tool

Comment: @AasimAzam write that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

### 2024 Update

The latest release of Adobe Illustrator, now has a dimensioning feature which *may* work for you.

---

##### Original 2017 answer below

**HotDoor.com** offers the [CadTools plug in](https://www.hotdoor.com/cadtools/overview) for Illustrator. It's designed to bring some CAD features into Illustrator, including dimensioning. HotDoor has been around since the 80s or 90s, so they aren't a "fly-by-night" developer in any sense.

> [image]

I've never really used it in any sort of "robust" manner. So, I can't directly state whether it's suitable for you or not. But it's worth a shot. There is a free demo.

---

Comment: Yes but that's not auto dimesnioning. Its more like manual dimensioning. Auto dimesnioning actually knows howe a object should be dimensioned to me a complete description of the thing

Comment: I know Joojaa :) But if one knows Illustrator this *might* be enough.

Comment: Well sure, but if this is the case then the list of potential applications that fulfills the need is staggering